# Taking 2 separated Data and insert in SQL database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql

This is a bit complicated but i managed to get this far until now.

http://medieproduktion.mediacollege.dk:10279/Game1/

If you go this site, the first your will be asked is so fill out Navn:(name), Email(email) and select your college.
you can do it since it is all working so please try it.

When you hit the "Start spillet" ( start the game) button then the data you just entered is inserted into my sql database. That works also.

Then you are redirected to the game as you can see. (use crome or firefox) IE dont work with the game. as soon as you click "start spillet" you will noticed at the top the counter is start to go down. and here comes the tricky part.

I want it to add the time used ( 120 sec - "remaining time" ) to the current datainput the user just typed in.

Here is teh Code for the counter :

```
var timeLeft = 120;
function decrementCounter() {
if (timeLeft > 0) {
    document.all('counter').innerHTML = "Tid tilbage " + timeLeft + "...";
    timeLeft--;
    setTimeout("decrementCounter()", 1000);
    document.getElementById("start_button").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("blackout").style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    window.location = "Failed.aspx";
     }
}
```

I will provide you with the entire solution if you want.

as i said, everything is working except i dont know how to add the time into the database at the current users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pm for the correct answer I think you would apricate it alot ; )!